# Cannot connect to OData with Excel 2013 without PowerQuery

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, power-query

I need to connect to Odata sources using Excel 2013 in an environment where we are not able to install PowerQuery on most user machines.

Excel 2013 has an option for getting data from Odata feeds, but it doesn't seem to work at all. I can only get it to work with Power Query.

I am using the Odata.org Northwind demo Odata feed at https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/

[image]

I have tried it with "use the sign-in information for the person opening this file" option, and also with "use this sign-in name and password, trying blank username, "guest", "anonymous"

I always get this error:

[image]

Then this one:

[image]

If I create a connection to the **V3** demo data using powerquery, then disable power query and try to refresh it, I get:

[image]

If I create a connection to the **V2** demo data using power query, then disable power query and try to refresh it, I get:

[image]

I can remember loading OData in excel years ago, but now it seems to be not possible any more? Please advise what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try to [enable TLS 1.2](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX245765).

Comment: On the client computer?

Comment: Yes, since you don't control the server.

Comment: I don't in this proof of concept, but I will in the ultimate solution. If I need to enable TLS 1.2 on all the client machines who will be connecting to this when I'm done, it will be difficult to roll out.

Comment: The site you gave uses TLS 1.2, as it's an old server. For your site that is under your control, you may use anything you like.

Comment: It looks like there are no enabled protocols on these client machines. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHAN
NEL\Protocols is empty

Comment: Will that mean that OData will not work at all for us?

Comment: Not at all, it's just this one source that you're using as test.

Comment: Have you managed to make it work?